# redux-thunk get error : Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

I create a React App, and I need to make an async request with Redux,
I want to use redux-thunk to get but get this error.

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

this is my code:

```
export function firewall(state = { data: [], loading: false, error: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTED_DATA_FAILED':
      return {
        data: [],
        loading: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case 'REQUESTED_DATA_SUCCEEDED':
      return {
        data: action.data,
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case 'REQUESTED_DATA':
      return {
        data: [],
        loading: true,
        error: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
const requestData = () => {
  return { type: 'REQUESTED_DATA' }
};

const requestDataSuccess = (data) => {
  return { type: 'REQUESTED_DATA_SUCCEEDED', data: data }
};

const requestDataError = () => {
  return { type: 'REQUESTED_DATA_FAILED' }
};

export const getFirewall = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestData())
    request('/list', 'get')
      .then(res => 
       dispatch(requestDataSuccess(formatData(res.data))))
      .catch(error => dispatch(requestDataError()))
  }
}
```

and this is my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Reducers } from './reducer'

export const store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Comment: `return` the `request` in your `getFirewall` action creator. In addition, your other creators should be structured like so `export const example = (passedinparams) => dispatch => return dispatch({ type: example, payload: data })`

Comment: It seems like the thunk middleware is not "working". Please double check, maybe put a breakpoint inside it and see if it's called.